# H2 module not detected

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, h2, java-11

I am developing JavaFX app with Hibernate and H2 database using Java 11, All dependencies all imported through Gradle 5.6.2 using IntelliJ Idea 2019.1.4.

H2 automatic module name `com.h2database` is not detected despite the library being the import section

My `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

group 'org.sarc'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11

javafx {
    version = "11"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls','javafx.fxml' ]
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.8.Final'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'

}
```

And my `module-info.java` file:

```
module vtcc {
    requires java.sql;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires com.h2database;
}
```

Now, on the last require `intelliJ` tells me that `module is not in dependencies`

Comment: I don't know Gradle very well but should com.h2database be in the testCompile group?

Answer (score -1):

Switched to SQLite, worked perfectly